# letter frequency from a string in a file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Sample text file:

```
airport, 2007, 175702
airport, 2008, 173294
request, 2005, 646179
request, 2006, 677820
request, 2007, 697645
request, 2008, 795265
wandered, 2005, 83769
wandered, 2006, 87688
wandered, 2007, 108634
wandered, 2008, 171015
```

This text file contains a word (ex: 'airport'); a year and the number of times that word was used in that year. What I did was created a class which made the word a key and had the year and occurrences for that year. Now what I want to do is find the number of occurrences of each letter from a to z. This is done by finding how many times each letter in the alphabet occurs in the word then multiply that number but the total number of occurrences of that word plus the same for the other words.

example:

'a'; appears once in both wandered and airport so we get 1(83769+87688+108634+171015) = 451106 total occurrences for 'a' in wandered and 1(175702+173294) = 348996 total occurrences for 'a' in airport which come to a total of 800102 times the letter a has appeared. To find the frequency which 'a' appears we divide 800102 by the total number of letter in all which is 25770183 and that gives a frequency of 0.013047 of the letter 'a'. 'b' and 'c' would be 0.0 since no words are currently using those letters.

this is what i have so far but its not working at all and I am out of ideas:

```
from wordData import*

def letterFreq(words):
    totalLetters = 0
    letterDict = {'a':0,'b':0,'c':0,'d':0,'e':0,'f':0,'g':0,'h':0,'i':0,'j':0,'k':0,'l':0,'m':0,'n':0,'o':0,'p':0,'q':0,
                  'r':0,'s':0,'t':0,'u':0,'v':0,'w':0,'x':0,'y':0,'z':0}

    for word in words:
        totalLetters += totalOccurances(word,words)*len(word)
        for char in range(0,len(word)):
            for letter in letterDict:
                if letter == word[char]:
                    for year in words[word]:
                        letterDict[letter] += year.count
    for letters in letterDict:
        letterDict[letters] /= totalLetters


    print(letterDict)

def main():
    filename = "data/very_short.csv"
    words = readWordFile(filename)
    letterFreq(words)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: I was thinking of making a list from a-z and using that to compare all the letters of the word.

Comment: What does *"its [sic] not working at all"* mean, exactly? And where is `readWordFile`?

Comment: i have a separate .py file that has a class and function that are being called in this .py file. my program correctly get the total number of letters of all word occurrences in the file, what is not working the find the frequency of each letter in the file

Comment: So what does *"not working"* mean? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the count of all the letters in the file use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        c.update(line.split(",")[0])
    print(c)
Counter({'e': 16, 'r': 12, 'd': 8, 'a': 6, 't': 6, 'n': 4, 'q': 4, 's': 4, 'u': 4, 'w': 4, 'i': 2, 'o': 2, 'p': 2})
```

To get total just multiply by the times it appears:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        word, year, count = line.split()
        c.update(word*int(count))

 print(c["a"] / float(sum(c.values())))
```